# ajax url showing 404 not found on server but working on local codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

working on codeigniter project and created a ajax based form in which country , state and cities are added in my form by ajax and this is my ajax jquery function

```
$('#country-dropdown').on('change', function() {
    var country_id = this.value;
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?=base_url();?>get-states",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            countryId: country_id
        },
        success: function(result) {
            $("#state-dropdown").html(result);
            $('#city-dropdown').html('<option value="">Select State First</option>');
        }
    });
});

$('#state-dropdown').on('change', function() {
    var state_id = this.value;
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?=base_url();?>get-cities",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            stateId: state_id
        },
        success: function(result) {
            $("#city-dropdown").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

pretty simple
and these are my routes

```
$route['get-states']['post'] = 'backend/admin/others/Ajaxcontroller/getStates';
$route['get-cities']['post'] = 'backend/admin/others/Ajaxcontroller/getCities';
```

my controller

```
    public function getStates()
    {
        $this->load->model('StateModel', 'states');

        $countryId = $this->input->post('countryId');
        $states = $this->states->getStates($countryId);
        
        $html = '<option>Select State</option>';
        foreach($states as $state) {
            $html .= '<option value="'.$state->id.'">'.$state->name.'</option>';
        }

        echo $html;
    }

    public function getCities()
    {
        $this->load->model('CityModel', 'cities');

        $stateId = $this->input->post('stateId');
        $cities = $this->cities->getCities($stateId);
        
        $html = '<option>Select City</option>';
        foreach($cities as $city) {
            $html .= '<option value="'.$city->id.'">'.$city->name.'</option>';
        }

        echo $html;
    }
```

and my model

```
 public function getStates($countryId)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id ,name FROM rvd_states WHERE country_id = $countryId ORDER BY name;");
        return $query->result();
    }

public function getCities($stateId)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id ,name FROM rvd_cities WHERE state_id = $stateId;");
        return $query->result();
    }
```

it is working very very fine in my localhost but when i switched my code to production this same ajax shows not found url

any idea or suggestion what is happening there

also there is no change in my url
when i am in localhost this url returns data

```
http://localhost/matrimonial/get-states
```

but when i am in production this url

```
https://host.com/matrimonial/get-states
```

return 404

my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

please any help

Comment: check out your server configuration

Comment: what kind of configuration?

Comment: if you are using apache server theres a file called .htaccess it includes your configuration, your local and host configuration maybe not similar thats why this error occur

Comment: so what can i do now??

Comment: <?php echo base_url();?>  in ajax path, also check in network tab url for ajax call is it same what this should be? also check ajax url by direct hit/open directly in browser to check if this is accessible or not

Comment: i have already given base_url() output above i.e https://host.com/matrimonial and also i have manually hit that url but it shows not found

Comment: have you change the `base_url();` path in `config.php` in `production`???

Comment: i have tried but nothing happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post your .htaccess file code.

Also check controller file name. On live server first character of Controller file Name should be capital.

Comment: added in my question

Comment: Did you check filename, as i said ?

Comment: controller file name is OK sir but I think on server name are case sensitive is it so??

Comment: On live server. Physical file name should starts from Capital letter.

Comment: yes it was from capital letter but it was in UpperCamelCase so thats the problem 
thanks

Comment: Is your issue resolved ?

Comment: yes sir it was camelcase issue